# Using a Windows 7 laptop as an 802.1x authenticator & authentication server

Tags: windows-7, wired-networking, 802.1x

I am aware that I can make a Linux image act as an 802.1x Authenticator and authentication server by configuring a combination of hostapd and freeRADIUS (see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1059987/how-can-i-quickly-set-up-a-lab-with-802-1x-wired-authentication-without-a-swit)).

However, I'm being asked if we can use a Windows 7 laptop as the Authenticator and Authentication server. Is there an equivalent (combination of) software packages that can be used to use 802.1x authentication on the wired interfaces of the windows 7 laptop?

Comment: As far as built-in options go, only Server editions of Windows include this.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Do you know of any third party solution?

Comment: Twisty is right, this is normally a network server role. Radius server to be exact. Even if you do find a third party solution to run on top win7, I wouldn't recommend it.